# Установка минимального времени показа окна загрузки в андроид

Tags: java, android, sleep

Подскажите, как сделать задержку, чтобы вместе с вызовом функции `Load()` она была не меньше определенного времени. Обычный `sleep()` тут не подойдет. По идее, мне нужна функция, возвращающая текущее время, и с помощью нее посчитать сколько милисекунд выполнялась `Load()`,  если время меньше минимального, то подождать оставшееся в `sleep()`.

Другой вопрос, а стоит ли ставить задержку на экран загрузки приложения?

Answer (score 2):

Засекаете время при помощи *[System.nanotime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)* в начале выполнения инициализации и в конце. Если меньше, то досыпаете при помощи `Thread.sleep()` (в отдельном потоке), либо `Handler.postDelayed()` (в основном).

На android стоит делать экран загрузки приложения только если вас заставляют. В остальных случаях его нужно не делать.